# UIImagePickerController Leaks for Iphone Only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am getting a leak with the `UIImagePickerController` when exiting from the picture selection back to the application.  This does not happen every time but it does happen often.  Of interest is that it never happens when running on the iPad, just the iPhone and both are using the same code.  I am testing on actual devices and not the simulator and I am using ARC.

The leaked object is "UIStatusBarHideAnimationParameters". The leak is always 48 Bytes.  I read elsewhere to make sure to dismiss the delegate which I am doing via:

```
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    picker.delegate = nil;
}
```

The controller is being instantiated with the following:

```
-(void)imageFromCamera:(BOOL)camera
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    if (camera) imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    else imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Here is the delegate that is called when a picture is selected.  Of note, a picture does not need to be selected to cause this issue.  I can simply "cancel" and get this leak.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image;

    if (info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage])
    {
        image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    }
    else
    {
        image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    }

    self.fullUploadImage = image;
    self.thumbNailImage = [self resizeImage:image];

    imageSelected = YES;
    [self.sendButton setEnabled:YES];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    picker.delegate = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this using imagePicker like an iVar allocanting when and if you need:

in .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController  *imagePicker;
```

on .m

```
- (UIImagePickerController  *) imagePicker {
     if(!_imagePicker){
          _imagePicker = ((UIImagePickerController alloc) init)
     }
     return _imagePicker
}

-(void)imageFromCamera:(BOOL)camera
{
    if (camera) self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    else self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use a "getter".  Unfortunately the same issue still occurs.

Comment: are using some imagenamed function on picker delegate?

Comment: Are speaking of the didfinishPickingMediawithInfo delegate that is called?  I will copy that method in my OP above.

Comment: As I noted in my update, I don't actually have to select an image to cause this problem.  From the ImageVC I can tap "cancel" and still get the leak.